# SXA robots.txt configuration not recognized on bing an yahoo

Tags: sxa

on the settings of my site the robots txt does not seem to work for bing and yahoo , but works as expected for google , am i missing anything ??

[image]

Robots txt

[image]

Comment: can you please confirm below. 1. google is able to detect? 2. when u submit from yahoo, did u checked the logs what is coming out?

Comment: What happens if change the file contents to "User-agent: *
Disallow:"

Comment: Hi @Marcel , thanks for your reply , i want the crawlers to disallow /sitecore , i have not tried this

Comment: hi @VikashRaaj thanks for you reply , works as expected on google but does work on yahoo , no errors or warnings on logs

Comment: I would suggest that as long as you can confirm that the /robots.txt is outputting what you would expect (e.g. what's in the field shown in the image), then this is not a Sitecore issue.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because , this is general issue with a particluar search engines , not a Sitecore Issue